# Best way to include a header generated with configure_file

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

In a few packages, especially when porting third-party software to catkin, I encounter the problem of auto-generated headers. In a single-package scenario, it is pretty easy to handle, as I just have to play with `include_directories()` and the matter is settled.
As for the install space, an appropriate `install()` rule easily takes care of it.
Things get more complicated when dealing with devel space. For example, I would like my `fooConfig.cmake` to contain a link to the devel space include folder, that would contain the header generated from a template with `configure_file()`, for example. The same goes with pkg-config files.

I looked around and could not find any documentation or best practices on the matter.
So far, I have tested adding a `cmake/foo-extras.cmake.in` file like the following:

```
if(@DEVELSPACE@)
  list(APPEND @PROJECT_NAME@_INCLUDE_DIRS @CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX@/include)
endif()
```

and then in my `CMakeLists.txt` I have something akin to this:

```
catkin_package(
  CFG_EXTRAS foo-extras.cmake
)

set(devel_pkg_inc ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/include/${PROJECT_NAME})

configure_file(foo.h.in ${devel_pkg_inc}/foo.h)
install(FILES ${devel_pkg_inc}/foo.h DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION})
```

It does the job for me, but it looks a bit clunky.
Is there any catkin-ish way of doing this?
Am I missing anything obvious?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154281/best-way-to-include-a-header-generated-with-configure_file/) by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 411 on 2014-04-17

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-18**:
cc @Dirk Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The proposed way is ok.
Generating the header into the devel space is exactly what should be done.
Also the install rule is necessary - as is.

But you can achieve the same functionality without an extra file.
First to make it work for code compiler in your package you need to add the include folders:

```
# also assuming that you also have static headers in the include folder of your package
include_directories(include ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/include)
```

You should always only add the `include` folder (rather then the package specific subfolder in it) and then include your code with the package name as a namespace (e.g. `#include <pkgname/myheader.h`).

Second to make packages work which depend on yours you have to export both include locations:

```
catkin_package(INCLUDE_DIRS include ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/include)
```

For the install case it will work correctly since the `include` folder in install space will contain your static headers form the package `include` folder (if you have also installed them) as well as the header installed from the devel space. Again keep in mind that all your headers should be in a subfolder of `include` and should also be referenced like this in code.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2014-04-19**:
Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted to know. To be honest, I was looking at INCLUDE_DIRS but was thinking that introducing a devel space path in it might not play nicely with the install space rules. Now I know that it's fine, and getting rid of this -extras.cmake file is a relief.

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2014-04-28**:
Unfortunately, it did not work: `CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:336 (message): catkin_package() include dir '/Users/paul/test_ws/devel/include' is neither an absolute directory nor exists relative to '/Users/paul/test_ws/src/foo'`

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2014-05-05**:
I had to add this before catkin_package: file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/include)